# Disable Outbound email or change SMTP server with an SQL Query?

Tags: email

How can I activate the "Disable Outbound email" option or change the SMTP server address with only an SQL Query?

(My use case is when I copy live data to a test environment, I obviously want to make sure no real emails are sent from the test environment!)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. To see current value, run:

```
select * from civicrm_setting where name='mailing_backend';
```

Because it's PHP serialise format, there is no easy change to change one value only! Sigh. I would recommend setting your app to dummy variables, then running the above to get the current value, then sticking that in a update statement to give you something like:

```
update civicrm_setting set value='a:10:{s:15:"outBound_option";s:1:"0";s:5:"qfKey";s:37:"xxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:8:"entryURL";s:131:"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx";s:13:"sendmail_path";s:0:"";s:13:"sendmail_args";s:0:"";s:10:"smtpServer";s:9:"localhost";s:8:"smtpPort";s:2:"25";s:8:"smtpAuth";s:1:"0";s:12:"smtpUsername";s:0:"";s:12:"smtpPassword";s:0:"";}' where name='mailing_backend';
```

Hopefully, in future that update statement will set your SMTP settings back to dummy variables!

Comment: Could be make with a regex to avoid change the another params (in mariadb works, not sure mysql)

```sql
UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'outBound_option\";s:1:\"[0-9]','outBound_option\";s:1:\"5') WHERE name = "mailing_backend";
```

Answer (score 4):

In civicrm.settings.php, add the following:

```
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', 1);
```

This will route all email to files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/mail (Drupal) or media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog (Joomla).

You can also specify:

```
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', "your_file_path");
```

to set a specific output file.

See https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers.

Another option is to perform the following queries to kill any scheduled or queued mail:

```
UPDATE `civicrm_mailing_job` SET `status`= 'Complete' WHERE `status` IN ('Scheduled', 'Running', 'Paused')
DELETE FROM `civicrm_mailing_spool` WHERE 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the mail log! Will test soon. Good call on the `civicrm_mailing_spool` trick, tho that only stops existing emails, and I'd like to change the settings to also stop any new emails that might be made in testing.

Comment: Yes civicrm_mail_log is an excellent solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_reroute_email module and enable it on test env, which will reroute all CiviCRM emails to the specified email address. This will work with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small **drush** plugin that just does this. It also disables the standard drupal email.

 `function drush_modulename_commandname(){
    drush_print('Disabling outgoing email - drupal & civi');
    civicrm_initialize();
    $result = civicrm_api3('Setting', 'create', array(
        'mailing_backend' => array('outBound_option'=> CRM_Mailing_Config::OUTBOUND_OPTION_REDIRECT_TO_DB),
    ));
    if($result["is_error"]){
       drush_log('CiCRM Error'.$result['error_message'],'ok');
    }
    variable_set('mail_system',array (
     'default-system' => 'TestingMailSystem',
     'mimemail' => 'TestingMailSystem',
    ));
    drush_print('Done');
  }`
 
Information how to create drush commands can be found on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/commands/